# RecyclerView onItemClick Listener

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

How to implement `RecyclerView` **onItemClick** listener as we do with ListView, this is my old Adapter class using `ListView`:

```
public class GenreAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

....

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.textTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.textTitle.setText(genreArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {                          

           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putSerializable("data", genreArrayList);
           bundle.putInt("current", position);             

           Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieActivity.class);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           intent.putExtras(bundle);
           context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textTitle;
}
```

**MainFragment.java:-**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        /* Initialize recycler view */
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));

        list = new ArrayList<MainPoho>();
        adapter = new MainAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        .......

}
```

And here is my new `Adapter` class using `RecyclerView` :

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedListRowHolder> {

    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        FeedListRowHolder mh = new FeedListRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);        
        feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(feedItemList !=null){
            return feedItemList.size();
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
    }
```

---

```
public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView title;

    public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
```

**FeedItem.java:-**

```
public class FeedItem {
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

first store whole view in your viewHolder:

```
  public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     protected TextView title;
     protected View mRootView;

    public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mRootView = view;
    }
```

then set click listener at `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
    FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);        
    feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
    feedListRowHolder.mRootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks but it only works when i do tap on text in a row, whereas in a listview wherever we do tap in a row that works... so what could be the reason ?

Comment: i think if you set the click listener to the rootview you will get what you want.

Comment: I do not know exactly what your problem is, I saw your other post, sorry right now I can not create any sample project to test but I have implemented what I posted exactly in one of my app:-(

Comment: i am not looking for any sample project, my concern is why click not responding when i do tap on row

Comment: the `mRootView` is already available when you extend `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, but is called `itemView`

Comment: Don't add click listener to the onBindViewHolder method it would create a new onClickListener object for every item in the list. Add it to your custom ViewHolder instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to implement your own OnItemTouchListener :

```
static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                //here get the view that has been touched
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());

                //now pass the item and its position to your click listener 
                if(child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                    clickListener.onClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        //use the gesture detector to intercept singletap and longtouch events
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }
}
```

And then you will have to implement the ClickListener that will be called by the RecyclerTouchListener above :

```
private RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener mClickListener =  new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            //Do something with your item...
            mRecyclerAdapter.getElementAt(position).doSomething();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little late but for all those who wander and are not lost. I found this elegant solution [here](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/).

So basically you create a ItemClickSupport class like below

```
public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
        = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

And then in your activity/fragment where you have defined and bind your recyclerView just do the following

```
//Here the mRecyclerView is the name of the defined recyclerView
ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
        // do it
    }
});
```

Also, you need to create an ids.xml file inside your res/values folder and define the  following inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id" />
</resources>
```

I hope this helps. Still recommend you to go through the [article](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/) to read more regarding it.