# RecyclerView facing small Issues

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` in my program, and facing some small issues, I believe some of you already faced and resolved all of them..

1. `Separator color`: Using [DividerItemDecoration.java](https://gist.github.com/lapastillaroja/858caf1a82791b6c1a36) to show separator between Items, but don't know where to make change if i want to change separator line color (like : default to white color)
2. `Clickable Row`: click only works when i do tap on text in a row, but i want to allow user to click anywhere in a row (like: listview)
   following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912253/recyclerview-onitemclick-listener) link
3. `Wrap RecyclerView` : I have only two records in a recyclerview but its consuming full height (I want to wrap it based on records in a RecyclerView, like : listview)
4. `Ripple Effect`: Whenever i do tap on any of the item in a RecyclerView not getting RippleEffect whereas when i do click on list item getting Ripple Effect
5. `RecyclerView Item Animation`: How can i achieve animation when i do tap on any of the item in RecyclerView

**fragment_main.xml:-**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"/>
```

**adapter_main.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ListTextView"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml:-**

```
<style name="AppTheme.ListTextView" parent="android:Widget.Material.TextView">
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>            
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

**btn_rounded.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#008f8471"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

**MainAdatper.java:-**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainHolder holder, final int position) {
    .....
    holder.mRootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strTitle = list.get(position).getTitle().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", strTitle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**MainFragment.xml:-**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        /* Initialize recycler view */
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));

        list = new ArrayList<MainPoho>();
        adapter = new MainAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        .......

}
```

Comment: Check the post [Should we use RecyclerView to replace ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview)

Answer (score 6):

**1.**

First, create a drawable xml file that will represent the divider like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- or you could use hex i.e. #ffffff -->
    <size android:height="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Then set that divider to your `DividerItemDecoration` like this:

```
new DividerItemDecoration(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.recycler_divider))
```

**2.**

Without seeing how you are inflating your `ViewHolder` I don't know what `mRootView` really represents, but here is the approach that I typically take. I would create the item view much like you did, but with a couple changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <!-- This will give your recycler item the ink ripple effect and touch state -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ListTextView"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder(...)` method you're going to want to set the `OnClickListener` to the `itemView` object in the holder like so:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainHolder holder, final int position) {
    .....
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strTitle = list.get(position).getTitle().toString();

            /**
             * Here is where I would typically create a java interface to use as a
             * callback to the fragment/activity/whatever to take action rather
             * than keeping this code in the adapter
             */

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", strTitle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This should let you use the entire cell as a clickable area + the ripple effect.

**3.**

Making the RecyclerView wrap its content vertically is a little tricky. You have to subclass the `LinearLayoutManager` and override it's `onMeasure(...)` method to force it to wrap it's content. Refer to this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616854/1623828

**4.**

See my answer to #2. You have to give the background (or foreground) of the view you're setting the `OnClickListener` to the value `?attr/selectableItemBackground` or `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` if you want the ripple to go beyond the bounds of the view. This value will use the ink ripple selector when on 5.0+ and will default to your standard no ripple selector on any platform that is lower. You can however create your own custom ripple drawable, but that is a little more involved.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Touch

**5.**

What kind of animations? Like, RecyclerView item animations? For those you can create your own animations by subclassing [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html) and applying it by using this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setItemAnimator(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator)):

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(...)
```

or you can use the [default implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.html):

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator())
```

**Otherwise** do you mean animating between Activities using Activity Transitions? If so you can follow the documentation **[here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)** to setup Activity Transitions, however they will only work on **Android 5.0+**

Comment: I have marked your answer as useful, and  for onClick, I am following this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912253/recyclerview-onitemclick-listener

Comment: Do you realise that there is no default implementation of DividerItemDecoration? For example example I found doesn't have a constructor with drawable param

Comment: Yes, there is no default implementation, however I was referering to the [DividerItemDecoration.java](https://gist.github.com/lapastillaroja/858caf1a82791b6c1a36) linked in the original post

Answer (score 0):

As alternative solution to all points (but 4), recently I've improved and created a **FlexibleAdapter** pattern for all RecyclerView.
Very simple to use, just copy 2 classes in your common files + some xml in order to enable the selection (Single/Multi) as it was for ListView.

Please have a look at the description and full working example: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter

For the point 4 the reason because you should give up it's because it is very complex and that solution (that works wrapping) could have incredible impact like *loops* while you combine it with selection and `notifyXXX()`. Strange to say but when I used it I started to have troubles and slowness while scrolling. So i removed and now I use the default one: LinearLayoutManager.

For last point (5), here there are many fancy animations: http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/03/unlocking-recyclerview/